# How does JavaScript evaluate : (colon)

Tags: javascript, syntax

A small question:

In my Browser(GoogleChrome) console if I type

```
abc:xyz:123
```

it evaluates to

```
123
```

How does JavaScript evaluate `:`?

Comment: Could you poste a complete example? Google Chrome throws syntax error for this code.

Comment: That is called a label.

Comment: I am using console, it does not throws error, just type abs:xyz:123

Answer (score 10):

Both `abc` and `xyz` are treated as loop labels. Quoting from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label),

> Provides a statement with an identifier that you can refer to using a
>   break or continue statement.
>
> For example, you can use a label to identify a loop, and then use the
>   break or continue statements to indicate whether a program should
>   interrupt the loop or continue its execution.

Also, check [Avoid using labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label#Avoid_using_labels) section,

> Labels are not very commonly used in JavaScript since they make
>   programs harder to read and understand. As much as possible, avoid
>   using labels and, depending on the cases, prefer calling functions or
>   throwing an error.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what is happing is `abc` and `xyz` are being treated as labels.  So 2 labels are being created and then the statement of `123` is being evaluated which gives you the result of `123`